# ubiquity preseed prompting user after default set

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ubiquity

With the alternate (non-ubiquity) installer, I can set an IP address with 
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 192.168.1.1
and then prompt the user to optionally change it with
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress seen false

How do I do this with ubiquity on the desktop installer as I don't seem to get any prompt (or any config set either) with any of the netcfg options as the ubiquity gui doesn't sem to have any hooks into the debian-installer to collect user data.